# K-means performance

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I have a large dataset that each sample has a specific class number from 0 to 8. I used K-means algorithm from sklearn python package. The output of K-means is different when I run codes for several times. For example, the 246th sample belongs to cluster 3 in the first run, and it belongs to cluster 0 in the second run. I have also attached an image for your consideration.

I think it's because of random initialization for cluster centers but I need to have a constant result in several runs. How can I fix it? [image]

Comment: Are you sure cluster_number 3 and 0 are not the same? `kmeans.cluster_centers_ `

Comment: Absolutely they are the same. But I wanna calculate the k-means performance by comparing the correct cluster ID and k-means cluster ID, and so I need a stable result for the rest of my code.

Comment: well, they won't ever be or just by chance since the algorithm starts by randomly placing centroids and then optimize their position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of cluster are not a real data, it’s random number to differenced cluster one from one.
Then it’s not to make stable number.

To know real type of class it’s need to associate known class and mnemonic number.

Your sample:

1  : 246 is #3

2 : 246 is #0

Your need to give name to [246]

Comment: Yes I have also mentioned your point in my post. But I need to calculate the performance of k-means by the correct label of each sample and I need a stable result. Do you know how can I calculate the k-means performance by having the correct class ID for each sample?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter which label it is as long as 0's and 3's corresponding id's are same in both run. measuring performance is another issue, since it is unsupervised it is much trickier. you can check silhoutte score for that.  but in real life mostly it is based on your business.https://dzone.com/articles/kmeans-silhouette-score-explained-with-python-exam#:~:text=Silhouette%20score%20is%20used%20to,are%20similar%20to%20each%20other.&text=denoted%20by%20a-,Mean%20distance%20between%20the%20observation%20and%20all%20other,of%20the%20next%20nearest%20cluster.

Comment: Stable result is classification and mnemonic number. 
Your question is how get name (type) of class. It’s may be associating getting number from current fit with known samples. It’s combination classification and teaching

Comment: Associating : Your sample:

246 is #3

246 is #0. -  is your answer